# Matlab GUIDE Display Current Date in Edit Text box

Tags: matlab, user-interface, date, matlab-guide

I am making my very first GUI using GUIDE and I am running into a problem with one of my Edit Text boxes. The Edit Text box will require the user to enter a date using the mm/dd/yyyy format. I expect that the user will be entering the current date 99% of the time, so I would like to have the current date (in mm/dd/yyyy format) already entered in the text box for the user.

I was able to achieve something like this in Matlab's Command Window using

```
datestr(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

However, I am unsure where/how to implement this code into my GUI to get it to display the date. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `edit1` is the tag to the `editbox`, add this to `OpeningFcn` for the GUI -

```
set(handles.edit1,'String',cellstr(datestr(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')));
```

Thus, today's date would show up in the `editbox`, once the GUI loads up.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you need to use the "String" property of your edit box with the output from `datestr(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')`.

For instance:

```
set(handles.EditBox,'String',datestr(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

and that should do it. You can put this line in the Create Function of the edit box, so that when the user will open the GUI the text will already be there.

Hope that's what you meant!